# Icon displayed by windows 7 changes to default icon if executable is moved

Tags: c#, winforms, icons

My C# Window 7 winforms program displays my custom icon when it is run from the Visual Studio output directory.

When I move the executable to my desktop and run it, the default windows winforms
icon is displayed.

How do I get windows to display the correct icon when the executable is moved?

Comment: How did you include your icon?

Answer (score 0):

Your icons should be stored in a folder in your solution (best is 'solution\resources\images\X.extension') and added by the Visual Studio IDE (he creates a reference).
When you deploy your application, you should only give the user a shortcut of the executable. Here is the secret.